# What vine grows purple grapes which taste like lollipops?

Tags: fruits, variety-selection, grape-vine

When I was younger lots of people we knew had grape vines with grapes that tasted quite a lot like the grape lolly flavour. (I guess it's the grape they designed that flavour from.)

They had purple skin and white flesh.

I was just wondering if anyone knows the variety I'm talking about as I would really like to get one for my garden. I've asked around and looked online but can't find what type I'm looking for.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is the Concord grape, which due to some diligent and patient planting and tasting of wild born vitis riperia vines one was discovered that tastes good for tables and juice and was named Concord. This is also the grape that was first used to make "grape flavor" but I think it is now synthesized.

Comment: Awesome thanks, just what I was looking for